# Win32 Browse for folder dialog: wrong folder returned when user creates a new folder

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi

I've noticed what seems to be a bug in the browse for folder dialog:

1. Open the new style browse for folder dialog that has a "New Folder" button.  (E.g. FolderBrowserDialog class in .NET Framework, or SHBrowseForFolder in Win32 C++).
2. Click the "Create New Folder" button to create a new folder.
3. Type a name for the new folder. Do NOT press Enter or click anything to stop editing the new folder name after you are done typing it in.
4. While the cursor is still blinking / the edit box is still active, click the OK button.  You must click the OK button very quickly.
5. Instead of returning the new name of the folder to the program, the dialog returns "New folder" directory.  For example, `C:\New Folder` instead of what the user typed in, e.g. `C:\My App Data Files`.

My guess is that the dialog's OK button reads the folder name from the treeview in the button's "click/mouse-up" event.  If you click it fast enough, the dialog reads the old value "New folder" since the treeview hasn't had enough time to process the rename.

The end result is that the dialog returns the path to a directory that no longer exists (since it was renamed) and the application then fails.

I can reproduce this on my Windows 7 developer workstation, but it's not limited to that computer.  It's been reproduced both in our production C++ application and a prototype C# application.

Has anyone else seen this and knows of a workaround / fix?  This new-style dialog has been around since Windows 2000; I can't believe this hasn't been seen/fixed by now, but I can't find the details!  I know it can be worked around by the user by e.g. pressing Enter, waiting a moment, then clicking OK.  But it seems that users with less computer experience don't know that and it trips them up.  So I'm looking for a programmatic workaround / fix.

Comment: This behavior has been around forever. It probably hasn't been fixed because nobody cares enough, since the workaround is so trivial (click on another node, then back on the new node).

Comment: Also this isn't really a programming question, is it?

Comment: @IgbyLargeman: Perhaps it's a stretch, but the question seems to be "Can this problem be alleviated, programmatically?"

Comment: It's a programming question because our software that we write exhibits this behavior, and I've seen it trip up our users who don't know better.  I know you can just click another node and then click back (or press Enter and wait a moment), but apparently not all of our users know that!  I'm looking for a programmatic workaround.

Comment: @Drew: exactly, I guess I should have more explicitly stated that.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224342

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend setting your ambitions low, since you're effectively trying to bugfix the OS itself at this point.

Consider checking if `GetFileAttributes(folderName) == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES` after the dialog exits.

If that expression is true, present the dialog again.  That will at least prevent crashes or other failure scenarios.

Comment: Ugly but I guess that will have to do for now.  I'm sure using an IFileDialog-based dialog on Windows Vista/7 would be much better and not have these sorts of problems, but it doesn't help the XP customers so we'd have to do both ways for the time being - annoying!  (They really should have used IFileDialog in the Vista/7 version of SHBrowseForFolder).

Answer (score 2):

You could check for existence of the selected folder (a good practice anyway), and if it doesn't exist and is called "New Folder", get the parent folder, find the sub folder that was created a few seconds ago by the current user, and assume that's the one they wanted.

That will *probably* always work, but it's not foolproof, so it couldn't be considered robust.

The most robust solution is just to detect the condition and force the user to select the folder again.

It's a trade-off between risk and inconvenience.